# Getting Element type is invalid: expected a string in react codesandbox example

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Getting `Element type is invalid:` expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. in my react codesandbox link.
Could someone please advise to fix the issue.

Added codesandbox link:

https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-aryabhata-lktg6v?file=/src/App.js

// App.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import ProtectedRoute from "./components/protectedRoute";
import Login from "./components/login";
import Dashboard from "./components/dashboard";
import User from "./components/user";

export const App = () => {
  const [role, setRole] = useState();

  const switchAdmin = (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={() => <Login role={role} />} />
      <ProtectedRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
      <Route path="/user" exact component={User} />
    </Switch>
  );

  const switchUser = (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
      <Route path="/user" exact component={() => <User role={role} />} />
    </Switch>
  );

  return (
    <Router>
      <div>{role === "admin" ? switchAdmin : switchUser}</div>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

Comment: You are using `react-router` v6, see https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5

Answer (score 0):

you first of all, you have to change de definition of your function:

from:

```
export const App = () => {
```

to:

```
export default function App()
```

then you have to replace your code for this one:

```
export default function App() {
  const [role, setRole] = useState("user");

  const switchAdmin = (
    <Routes>
      <Route exact path="/" component={() => <Login role={role} />} />
      <ProtectedRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
      <Route path="/user" exact component={User} />
    </Routes>
  );

  const switchUser = (
    <Routes>
      <Route exact path="/" component={<Login role={role} />} />
      <Route path="/user" exact component={() => <User role={role} />} />
    </Routes>
  );
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Login role={role} />} />
        <Route path="/user" exact element={() => <User role={role} />} />

        <Route exact path="/" component={() => <Login role={role} />} />
        {/* <ProtectedRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} /> */}
        <Route path="/user" exact component={User} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
  // return (
  //   <BrowserRouter>{role === "admin" ? switchAdmin : switchUser}</BrowserRouter>
  // );
}
```

after that I recommend you to see this repository to know how to implement navigation and Authorization.
https://github.com/portisk8/AntDesign.Admin

Comment: Thank you very much ! Now it gives a white screen, One warning displayed is :  React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of `App`.
    at App (https://lktg6v.csb.app/src/App.js:32:41)
The above error occurred in the <Route.Provider> component:

In the above example, may i know how does the ``role ``` passed to app.js ?

Comment: you have to change each definition of your function found in these files:

* components/dashboard
* components/login
* components/user
* components/protectedRoute

Comment: Sorry  i have changed that too, but still some error >> https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-aryabhata-lktg6v?file=/src/components/login.js

Comment: In react-router-dom v6, you need to use useNavigate rather than useHistory
In Login.js it should look like this:
https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-silence-jbk220?file=/src/components/login.js:0-542